# После начала билдинга MacOS вылетает

Tags: swift, xcode

Скачал XCode версии 11.2.5 (не говорите мне про обновления). Создал проект, после запуска приложения на стадии:

[image: стадия]

у меня тупо пропадает мышка и через секунд 5 показывается окно входа в аккаунт MacOS. После входа XCode перезапускается и так каждый раз

Пробовал решения с [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451126/xcode-crashes-on-launch), но ничего не помогает.

Такое же происходит со Swift проектом:

[image: swift]

Comment: А MacOS какой версии? Если ставите старый Xcode, то и MacOS поставьте соответствующую.

Comment: XCode 11.2.5, macos big sur

Comment: Хм, Mac OS под требования подходит. Не хакинтош?

Answer (score 0):

Обновил до XCode 12.2 и билдится нормально